# How do I approximate a function in the form $z = f(x, y)$ of a real-life 3D surface?

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions, approximation, 3d

I have a set of points in the form $(x,y,z)$.

I need to estimate a 3D function in the form $z = f(x, y)$ for these points which form a surface that is a circular paraboloid.

The general formula for a circular paraboloid is $z = b(x^2 + y^2)$; $b$ is a constant.

Please HELP!

Comment: Please provide more context. Some things we need to know to answer this question: (1) Are the points exact or are they results of some kind of measurement which has an error (2) How are the points distributed (on a grid, randomly, if it's the latter, then are they distributed evenly on average or is there some clustering, etc)

Comment: Least squares for surfaces can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have $n$ data points $(x_k,y_k,z_k)$ and you wish to find a formula

$$  z^*=b(x_k^2+y_k^2)$$

which best fits the data in the least squares sense.

Can we assume that the $(x_k,y_k)$ are distributed uniformly inside a circle about $(0,0)$?

If so, since you have only one free variable, $b$, you can find the value of $b$ which minimizes

\begin{eqnarray} S&=&\sum_{k=1}^n(z^*-z_k)^2\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\left[b\left(x_k^2+y_k^2\right)-z_k\right]^2\\
&=&b^2\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^2+y_k^2\right)^2-2b\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^2+y_k^2\right)z_k+\sum_{k=1}^nz_k^2
\end{eqnarray}

So you want to find $b$ satisfying

$$ \frac{dS}{db}=0 $$

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dS}{db}&=&2b\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^2+y_k^2\right)^2-2\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^2+y_k^2\right)z_k\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore

$$ b=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^2+y_k^2\right)z_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^2+y_k^2\right)^2} $$

Comment: I think you mixed it up in the last step; your final formula gives $1/b$.

Comment: @Rahul  You are right. Evidently, I copied and pasted from the wrong brackets. Will fix.